# How to center a layout inside a scrollView on click?

Tags: android, uiscrollview

So I have this layout here:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/instructions">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Sample text 1"/>            

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Sample text 2"/>            

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Sample text 3"/>      


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

(I just made it up to textView3 for simplicity's sake, but say there's more and the scrollView is scrollable) then there is a button outside this scrollView. Every time the button is clicked the scrollView scrolls and centers the view to the next textView. How can I achieve this?

I've tried getting the height of the views then adding it up to use on the scrollView.scrollTo(y), but retrieving the height gave me lots of problems, I used the ViewTreeObserver process but I couldn't retrieve the height inside the

> .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(New ViewTreeObserver...

and place it on a variable. but I failed with this method. What am I doing wrong? or are there any easier approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using `RecyclerView` and add new items to the list and then call the `scrollToPosition(position)` function to scroll to the latest one. 
Don't forget to add `paddingBottom` to the `RecyclerView` to be able to scroll the last view into to center. (Use the `screenHeight / 2` for the `paddingBottom`)